# How to wait a js async function from golang wasm?

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly, language-interoperability

I have written a little function `await` in order to handle async javascript function from go:

```golang
func await(awaitable js.Value) (ret js.Value, ok bool) {
    if awaitable.Type() != js.TypeObject || awaitable.Get("then").Type() != js.TypeFunction {
        return awaitable, true
    }
    done := make(chan struct{})


    onResolve := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        glg.Info("resolve")
        ret = args[0]
        ok = true
        close(done)
        return nil
    })
    defer onResolve.Release()

    onReject := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        glg.Info("reject")
        ret = args[0]
        ok = false
        close(done)
        return nil
    })
    defer onReject.Release()

    onCatch := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        glg.Info("catch")
        ret = args[0]
        ok = false
        close(done)
        return nil
    })
    defer onCatch.Release()


    glg.Info("before await")
    awaitable.Call("then", onResolve, onReject).Call("catch", onCatch)
    // i also tried go func() {awaitable.Call("then", onResolve, onReject).Call("catch", onCatch)}()
    glg.Info("after await")
    <-done
    glg.Info("I never reach the end")
    return
}
```

The problem is that when I call the function with or without goroutine, the event handler seems blocked and I'm forced to reload the page. I never get into any callback and my channel is never closed. Is there any idiomatic way to call await on a promise from Golang in wasm ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need goroutines for that one :D

I see a few problems in this code that doesn't make it idiomatic and can lead to some errors (some of which might lock your callback and lead to this situation you're describing):

- You shouldn't close the `done` channel inside the handling function. This can lead to unwanted closing due to concurrencies and it's a bad practice in general.
- Since there's no guarantee in the order of execution, changing external variables might lead to some concurrency problems. It's best to communicate with the external functions using channels only.
- The results from `onResolve` and `onCatch` should use separate channels. This can lead to better handling of the outputs and sort out the results for the main function individually, ideally through a `select` statement.
- There's no need for separate `onReject` and `onCatch` methods, since they are overlapping each other's responsibilities.

If I had to design this `await` function, I'd simplify it a bit to something like this:

```golang
func await(awaitable js.Value) ([]js.Value, []js.Value) {
    then := make(chan []js.Value)
    defer close(then)
    thenFunc := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        then <- args
        return nil
    })
    defer thenFunc.Release()

    catch := make(chan []js.Value)
    defer close(catch)
    catchFunc := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        catch <- args
        return nil
    })
    defer catchFunc.Release()

    awaitable.Call("then", thenFunc).Call("catch", catchFunc)

    select {
    case result := <-then:
        return result, nil
    case err := <-catch:
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

This would make the function idiomatic, as the function would return `resolve, reject` data, kinda like a `result, err` situation that is common in Go. Also a bit easier to deal with unwanted concurrencies since we don't handle variables in different closures.

Last but not least, make sure you're not calling both `resolve` and `reject` in your Javascript `Promise`, as the `Release` method in `js.Func` explicitly tells that you should not access such resources once they are released:

```golang
// Release frees up resources allocated for the function.
// The function must not be invoked after calling Release.
// It is allowed to call Release while the function is still running.
```

Comment: Thanks it's works like a charm, my app was blocking because i was using fetch before calling await, now using a goroutine i can use your function !